# adding a slide to unlock or open button android

Tags: android, slide

I have an open screen to my app and I want to add a slide to unlock open button to that screen
so when the user will slide it he will enter the application.

can someone help me???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use GestureDetector and implement onFling Event. 
[One of the post to implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)